# Assigning an empty parent object

Tags: scripting, parent

I wrote an operator to create an empty object and then make it a parent to the currently selected object.  However, when I assign the parent object, the child object moves unless it is at the origin.  How can I keep that from happening?  Here is some code that demonstrates the problem:

```
class ObjectTest(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "myops.object_test"
    bl_label = "Array of current object"
    
    def execute(self,context):

        origobj = bpy.context.active_object
        bpy.context.scene.cursor.location = origobj.location

        bpy.ops.object.empty_add()
        objparent=bpy.context.active_object
        objparent.name=origobj.name+"Array"
        origobj.parent=objparent
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ObjectTest)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ObjectTest)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

I would like the empty parent object and the selected child object to be at the same location, not necessarily the origin.  I am trying to make a group of objects that can be moved together, and a parent seems like the best way.  I was using Blender 2.83, but I recently updated to 2.9.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: you need a relative matrix which I have explained here:
[https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44637/how-can-i-manually-calculate-bpy-types-posebone-matrix-using-blenders-python-ap](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44637/how-can-i-manually-calculate-bpy-types-posebone-matrix-using-blenders-python-ap)

Answer (score 2):

**Set `matrix_parent_inverse`**

See [Does a child object inherit the matrix from the parent?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169416/does-a-child-object-inherit-the-matrix-from-the-parent)

Key here is that the origin of local space is  calculated from the basis matrix (what you see in the transform UI) and its parent inverse matrix.

There are a number of ways to achieve desired result:

- set the empties matrix world to that of the original
- and set both the `matrix_basis` and `matrix_parent_inverse` of
  original to identity. *Equivalent to the one case that "didn't move"*

By default blender sets the matrix parent inverse, so when parenting is removed the object maintains its prior transform.  Using first method will snap them back to origin.

- Set parent matrix world to childs.
- Maintain the current location by setting childs `matrix_parent_inverse`
  to its inverted basis matrix.

Test script, method 2.

```
import bpy

class ObjectTest(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.test"
    bl_label = "Array of current object"
    
    def execute(self, context):

        ob = context.active_object

        bpy.ops.object.empty_add()
        mt = context.active_object
        mt.name = f"{ob.name}Array"
        mt.matrix_world = ob.matrix_world
        ob.parent = mt
        ob.matrix_parent_inverse = ob.matrix_basis.inverted()
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ObjectTest)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ObjectTest)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Consider extending this such to selected objects such that can add an empty parent to each, or one parent at active object and all other selected also become children.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  I have not yet had a chance to try it out, but it seems like it will solve my problem.  I have not heard of the basis matrix before, so also, thanks for the references to more info about it.

Comment: My code adds additional objects to the parent as they are created to make a group of objects that can be moved around together.  Your answer explains something that 
I did not understand, so I should be able to get the code to work now.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

you need relative transformation matrix which I have explained here:
[How can I manually calculate bpy.types.PoseBone.matrix using Blender's Python API?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44637/how-can-i-manually-calculate-bpy-types-posebone-matrix-using-blenders-python-ap)

Comment: Thanks.  Your explanation of the coordinate systems is helpful.