# Create empties and parent selection

Tags: python, parent, empty

I want to create an empty for every object selected (with its coordinates) and parent each object to the empty. I found this solution

[How to create an empty per object in selection?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134879/how-to-create-an-empty-per-object-in-selection)

In that link they share this code where it says "If you want the empties to be the parents :"

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:  # Loop over all selected objects
    empty = bpy.data.objects.new(obj.name + "_Empty", None)  # Create new empty object
    obj.users_collection[0].objects.link(empty)  # Link empty to the current object's collection
    empty.empty_display_type = 'PLAIN_AXES'
    empty.location = obj.location
    obj.parent = empty
    obj.location = (0, 0, 0)
```

But the nulls appear in the world's origin not in the objects' origin.

[image]

Any idea to get it?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What is the meaning of this sentence: "But the nulls appear in the world origin not in the object origin."

Comment: I edited the post, fixed my grammar errors and added an image, sorry

Comment: If you want to do this with python, please use the python tag on your question (I took the freedom to add it).

Comment: That seems to be most likely because every chain part is at the same location (world origin)

Comment: Every chain part has its own origin and not located in the world origin. In fact, when I apply the solution proposed in the link where the object is the parent it works perfectly placing the nulls in the parts' origins... but when making the empties the parents they appear at the world origin as shown above.

Comment: Same here, the code works as expected. There is something else specific to your objects setup

Comment: Ok, I applied All transforms to the objects and there is when the problem begins and the empties appear at the world origin. I need that objects whitout transforms... Can I apply transforms and get the emptys where the objects are?

Comment: Well, I tried and I can run the script and then apply all transforms. This way I get the parenting and clean transformations

Comment: could you share your file? that will help to try to see what is happening here

Comment: The chain parts have a delta transform. But without it they effectively are at the same location.

Comment: I think you need to read a bit more about what applying transform means. It will reset the origin of the object to the world origin. What you want is something like setting the empties at the center of mass or barycenter of geometry, because the origin is set to 0, 0, 0 when you apply the location